# Duplicate content

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I want to update a table SQL which content an ID + column already exist.

The problem is when I want to make the insert it gave me a message error:

```
**#1062 - Duplicate entry '35' for key 1**
```

So, I've try to make an UPDATE but it doesn't work too, because the syntax isn't correct the form of my request SQL is :

```
INSERT INTO `liens_series` 
(`id`, `id_series`, `password`) 
VALUES (35, '12', 
'<br>Saison 3 en cours de production'), ....
```

The list is too long.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause of the INSERT statement in MySQL.  Briefly, your statement might be changed to be

```
INSERT INTO `liens_series`
  (`id`, `id_series`, `password`)
VALUES
  (35, '12',  '<br>Saison 3 en cours de production')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_series` = '12',
                        `password` = '<br>Saison 3 en cours de production')
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
It will do what you want, insert or update if neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a new row of which the id isn't determined yet:

```
INSERT INTO `liens_series` (`id`, `id_series`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '12', '<br>Saison 3 en cours de production');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `liens_series` (`id_series`, `password`) VALUES ('12', '<br>Saison 3 en cours de production');
```

The new id will be returned in `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (MySQL) or `mysql_insert_id()` (C, PHP etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a row, and update its content if it already exists, use `REPLACE INTO`:

```
REPLACE INTO `liens_series` (`id`, `id_series`, `password`) VALUES (35, '12', '<br>Saison 3 en cours de production');
```

Note that behind the scenes, the row with id 35 will be deleted (if it exists) and then the `INSERT` issued. So you can't update the row only partially and the number of affected rows reflects the implicit number of DELETES + the number of INSERTS.